# Probability of choosing lottery ticket

Tags: probability, lotteries

There is a lot that contains 2 winning tickets out of 10 pieces. When 10 people draw this lot in order, the probability that the 10th person draws a winning ticket is?

Is this the same as choosing from 9 people, 1 person who gets the winning ticket?

Comment: The last person has the same chance as anyone else: $\frac15$

Answer (score 2):

The order of drawing does not matter at all.  Imagine lining up the people and lining up the tickets on the table.  Now draw from the other end and the last shall be first.

Comment: is the same as _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 1 , when the tenth person win , and choose from 9 , 1 people again who choose winning ticket? with sample space 10 C 2

Comment: If there are two winning tickets among $10$ the chance of a winner is $1/5$.  Everybody who draws gets the same chance.  It is not the same as choosing one of nine, which has chance $1/9$.  You are confusing yourself by thinking about the fact that at least one of the winners must be drawn before the last person draws.  That does not matter.

Comment: Thankyou but what is the relation of winning and choosing person who win(?) But choosing 1 of 9 with sample space 10C2 also produce same result(?)

Comment: I don't understand that last question at all.  Winning and choosing the person who wins are the same thing, just looked at from two different sides.  If you have two winning tickets out of ten, where does 1 of 9 come from?

Comment: i mean, let tenth person 1, so  there is still one win lottery left, _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 1 , from it C(9,1) / C(10/2) =1/5 why is this same? its coincidence?

Comment: No, it is not coincidence.  That is the correct way to compute the chance the last person gets a winner.  You have found the fraction of distributions that give exactly one ticket to the first nine, leaving one for the tenth.

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

The total possible combinations of 10 lottery tickets with 2 winning and 8 loosing is:
$10!/(8!*2!) = 45$ 
The total combinations of 1 winning ticket being at the end i.e the 10th person getting one is: $9!/8! = 9$
Therefore the probability comes out to be $9/45 = 1/5$

Comment: thankyou 9!/8! means choose 1 from 9?

Comment: @fiksx I think that is also true, you choose from total 9 people  1 person, given that already 1 has been given a winning ticket right ? The probability in your terms would be 9C1/ 10C2